# Struggling to write xpath / find a unique ID for an element

Tags: xpath, automation

For web automation purpose, I need a unique ID of a text/label, which has some white space around it.
please check the screenshots attached
one screenshot shows - the best I could right the xpath but it doesn't solve the problem
another screenshot shows - my idea but not successful.
as per screenshot, I need xpath for text called "Suresh Kumar YOGESH"[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//div[@class='text_head_detail_view_name_holder']/h1/text()[2]
```

**Screenshot:** with sample code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To complete supputuri's answer, another option (might be more secure) :

```
//span[contains(.,"Offenders")]/following::text()[1]`
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, your answer also works perfectly. Just added caps letter //span[contains(.,"Offenders:")]/following::text()[1]